# My adviser submitted an abstract to a conference that we submitted elsewhere before but changed the authors orders

Tags: phd, conference, authorship, abstract

About two months ago me and my adviser attended a conference, where he had a talk about my PhD project. For this talk, he submitted an abstract, where I was the first author and he was the second one. Yesterday, accidentally I became aware that he submitted the same abstract for an another conference but just flipped the order of authors. I didn't know that he's going to talk about my PhD project in that conference, but my main concern is that why he flipped the order of authors?! The title and abstract of the talk are the same verbatim as previous conference, so why the order of authors should be flipped?! My guess is that because this conference is much more prestigious than previous one, maybe he wanted to be first author, but that's not fair...

So, my main question is that should I say something or just let it go?

Comment: It may be the case that this conference requires that the presenting author be listed first--this is occasionally a requirement in conferences I've attended (at least in my field, biology)

Comment: Or it was an invited talk, and again the convention is that the invited speaker is first on the list.

Comment: I checked both of these possiblities and there is no requirement for first author to be presenter and it's not an invited talk.

Comment: Ask him. If your name is on something then you have a right to know.

Comment: In my field, both for conferences and invited talks, there are no requirements for author order. If this a verbatim from another conference, this definitely warrants a discussion with him to see what's going on.

Comment: Is this for a mathematics conference?  Does your adviser's last name alphabetically come before yours?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche No it's a physics conference but yes my adviser's last name come before mine alphabetically.